# Where is the best place to store cardboard?

Tags: garage, attic, storage

Having recently moved, a thrifty state of mind, and plenty of room for storage, taking into account mice, mold, and structural breakdown:

Would it be better to storage collapsed moving boxes in the garage attic or the basement?

I live near Indianapolis and the garage is not specially insulated, should climate need to be taken into account.

Comment: Cardboard is a great mulch, a fuel for fire, food for mold, home for rodents...I'd really suggest recycling.

Comment: @DA01 thank you for the heads up on on additional things to watch out for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to avoid anywhere damp, since moisture is an enemy of cardboard.  So a basement that isn't dry, would be a bad choice.  Mice won't seek out your cardboard, unless there's food in it.  They might chew it and use it for nesting material if they happen across it, but won't make seeking out cardboard a main part of their day.

I've had cardboard in the loft of my garage for over 5 years, with no problems.  I live in NY, so hot summers (80-90F) and cold winters (0-20F). The garage is detached and unconditioned, so it experiences hot humid days in the summer and bitter cold in the winter.

Cardboard is fairly hardy, and will last quite a long time if kept dry.  So anywhere that is out of your way and dry, would be a fine place to store it.

Comment: Do you simply pile them up on top of the rafters, or do you have any sort of mechanism to keep them on edge?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I just lay them flat in the loft, but I do have plywood down on top of the rafters so the cardboard does not sit directly on the rafters.

Answer (score 2):

I once stored a bunch of boxes in the loft of a barn. Black ants got to them and chewed on them.  Otherwise, no problem with temp or humidity. Use caution when piling too many on top of roof joists. Trusses aren't designed to hold too much weight in that direction.

Comment: Thank you for the note on weight, I plan to put down a thin  piece of wood to help distribute the weight a bit, and to make sure none of the boxes pile directly on top of the ceiling.